# C++ function warning

Tags: c++

WARNING: **refine.cpp: In member function 'bool CRefineManager::GetPercentage(CHARACTER*, BYTE, BYTE, BYTE, BYTE, CItem*)':
refine.cpp:60: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data                    type**

the problem is here
CODE:

```
bool CRefineManager::GetPercentage(LPCHARACTER ch, BYTE lLow, BYTE lMedium, BYTE lExtra, BYTE lTotal, LPITEM item)
{
    BYTE ar_ListType[3] = {lLow, lMedium, lExtra};

    for (int it = 0; it <= JOURNAL_MAX_NUM; it++)
    {
        if (ar_ListType[it] > 0)
        {
            //@fix 12.01.2017
            if (item->GetType() == ITEM_METIN)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (ch->CountSpecifyItem(EXTRA_REFINE_POTIONS_GRADE[it]) < 1)
            {
                ch->ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_INFO, LC_TEXT("refine_cannot_find_item"), ITEM_MANAGER::instance().GetTable(EXTRA_REFINE_POTIONS_GRADE[it])->szLocaleName);    
                return false;
            }
        }
    }   

    if (lTotal > 100 || lLow < 0 || lMedium < 0 || lExtra < 0) // Line 60
    {
        ch->ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_INFO, LC_TEXT("refine_overflow"));     
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

how can i solve it to don't be a warning anymore and works well without problems?

Comment: [Is `BYTE` an `unsigned char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types#BYTE)? In which case there is no point checking if any of these values are `< 0`, since an `unsigned char` can't store negative values. This is most likely the problem, but really we can't answer for certain without seeing a full [mcve] - it would be great if you could edit your question to be about a self-contained example.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is warning that `lLow < 0` and `lMedium < 0` and `lExtra < 0` can never be true because the smallest value a `BYTE` can have is zero.

It's impossible to tell from this code snippet whether this is a real problem or not. Possibly your thinking that `lLow`, `lMedium` and `lExtra` might be less than zero indicates a logic error on your part, in which case you have to rewrite your code somehow, or possibly it doesn't matter in which case you can simply delete `lLow < 0|| lMedium < 0 || lExtra < 0`.

I guess the crucial question is why you think it's necessary to check that `lLow` etc might be less than zero and why you made it a `BYTE` type.